# Login program from external text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having issues with a code where I have to get a user to type details about themselves, which saves to a text file. When the user tries to log in, it will check the text file for their details. Here is my code below. It works at first, where the user is granted access, but whenever I do a restart to my computer, or Python itself, it only grants the last user access. Some help would be appreciated, thank you:

This is what it looks like in the text file:

```
Adam16,adam123,Adam,Sunderland,16
Johnny18,johnny150,Johnny,Vane,18
```

This is the source code:

```
import csv

import sys

def register():

    firstname = input("First name: ")
    surname = input("Surname: ")
    age = int(input("Age: "))
    password = input("Password: ")

    username = firstname[:3] + str(age)

    with open("account.txt","a",newline="") as myfile:
        writer = csv.writer(myfile)
        writer.writerow([username,password,firstname,surname,age])
        myfile.close()

    menu()



def login():

    user0 = input("Username: ")
    pass0 = input("Password: ")


    file = open("account.txt","r")

    for line in file:
        details = line.split(",")



    if user0 == details[0] and pass0 == details[1]:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Fail")


    menu()

def menu():

    selection = int(input("1 or 2: "))

    if selection == 1:
        register()
    else:
        login()


menu()
```

Comment: Put the newline='' back in, sorry. the csv-module handles it itself. retracted answer. Open the created file in a text editor and paste its content (mask the pw) into your question (use code tags as well to preserve lineends)

Comment: I added what was currently in my text file at the top of the question thanks

Comment: see modified answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is identation - your `if user0 == details[0] and pass0 == details[1]:` is on the same indentation as the `for line in file:`- meaning it is executed *after* the for-loop not *inside* it and for each details. You are currently only ever checking the last `detail` you parse from your file.

You can fix this by indenting it correctly.

This would then lead to multiple outputs - if your user is on line 100 it will print 99 fails and 1 correct - thats why I would put the printing outside the for loop. You can use `break` to abort the loop as soon as you found the correct user.

Changing your login to this will accomplish that:

```
def login():

    user0 = input("Username: ")
    pass0 = input("Password: ")

    file = open("account.txt","r")
    foundOne = False

    for line in file:
        details = line.split(",")
        # execute Check on each line, not only on last line    
        if user0 == details[0] and pass0 == details[1]:
            foundOne = True
            break # this will instantly leave the for loop of line checkings

    if foundOne == True:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Fail")

    menu()
```

I indented the `if ...` so it is done for each line instead of only once. I also set a status to avoid printing `Fail` for each checked line.

Make sure to use the correct username - it is a combination of firstname and age

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have to try this at a later time, and I'll keep you updated. Really appreciate it

Comment: If it solves your problem, check the hook, if not, comment and I'll take a look

Comment: I have tried it, and it seems to be working now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that I don't like to do complete rewrites if I can avoid it, I prefer to give the answer to the problem with as much of the original code in place.

The reason your code doesn't do what you expect is this bit:

```
for line in file:
    details = line.split(",")
```

That only gives you the last line fed in as `details` is essentially overwritten every time the loop reads the next line in the file. You then come out of that for loop and check against `details`, so it only knows about the last line.

There's a number of ways you could go about this, I would suggest that the easiest is to use a dictionary instead of a list so that you can fill it up with the contents of the users file. You can also use csv.reader to read the csv file you created straight into a list without needing to split it first:

```
import csv
def login():

    user_dict = {}
    with open("account.txt", "r") as csvfile:
        authfile = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for line in authfile:
            user_dict[line[0]] = line[1:]

    user0 = input("Username: ")
    if user_dict.get(user0):
        pass0 = input("Password: ")
        if user_dict.get(user0)[1] == pass0:
            print("Correct!")
            menu()
        else:
            print("Bad Password")
    else:
        print("Bad Username")
```

The first section creates the user dictionary and fills it with the details you've saved to file. First entry (username) is the key and the rest of the details are stored in a list under that key.

From there, we get the username and then do a get request on the dictionary to make sure the user exists (`dict.get()` will return `None` if it fails and won't raise an exception). If the user exists, we ask for their password and check it. If the password matches it prints out the affirmative answer and loads your menu function. If not, the user is notified that they've supplied a bad password.

I hope that all made sense. Let me know if you have any questions.

edit: I may have misread this one. It looks like everything leads back to the menu function no matter what. I do believe I've engaged in a bit of overkill.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this later. Will get back to you on the results, and thank you for the in depth explanations as well.